# Titanium: Posting text to facebook app via intent Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, titanium

I developing an **Android** application using **Titanium Appcelerator**. I had tried to Post text to native **facebook** app installed in my mobile via **intent**. But i getting only the image posted in screen when i used the below code.

and i didnt get any errors. i get the facebook post screen , But i couldn't able to add prefilled text in it..

```
var intFB = Ti.Android.createIntent({
action : Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND,
packageName : "com.facebook.katana",
type : "image/jpeg"
});
intFB.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_TEXT, "text message..");
intFB.putExtraUri(Ti.Android.EXTRA_STREAM, image_file.nativePath);
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intFB);
```

What mistake i made in this..? clarify me please....

Thanku..

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to set the text.

Comment: @ Ming Li : But i want to.. is that noway possible,..?

Comment: It is against facebook's platform policies to prefill the text, so if you're using an intent to the FB app, they will strip out the text.

Comment: @Ming Li:Thank you..

Comment: var fb_data1 = {description:"text..",picture:imagepath.nativepath }; facebook_quote.dialog("feed", fb_data1, showRequestResult);    In this method i can able to add text, But when give local path for image..It says "Picture URL Not properly formatted"